# SignalR implementation error in Angular 6 with ng2-signalr package

Tags: asp.net, signalr, angular6

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SignalR -> InjectionToken SIGNALR_JCONNECTION_TOKEN]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SignalR -> InjectionToken SIGNALR_JCONNECTION_TOKEN]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken SIGNALR_JCONNECTION_TOKEN!

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem in Angular unit testing with karma. I have solved this problem by mocking singalR provide. It was not a part of code which I was testing. My solution is:

create custom mock class such us:

```
export class SignalRMock {
  public createConnection(options?: any): any {
    return null;
  }

  public connect(options?: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>(null);
  }
}
```

then use it as a stub in testing module:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        {provide: SignalR, useClass: SignalRMock},
        SignalRConfiguration
      ]
    });
```